# Is not less than "value" vb.net

Tags: vb.net, logical-operators

I want to add another logical condition. Which is "is not less than 1".

```
If DataGridView1.Item(6, i).Value <= 90 Then
```

Comment: Use `AndAlso` if you want to use multiple conditions. If only one of them must be true use `OrElse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is Not less than" you mean "Greater than or equal to?" i.e., `>='

So:

`If DataGridView1.Item(6, i).Value <= 90 
      And DataGridView1.Item(6, i).Value >= 1 Then`

Comment: Use `AndAlso` instead of `And`. The former uses short-circuiting